# Method used to fetch the user's friends picture with RestFB?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I want to display the pictures and names of user's friends, but `getPicture()` method doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone tell me what method will be used to get the picture of the user's friends?

My code is

```
Connection<User> myFriends = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/friends", User.class, Parameter.with("fields", "id,name,picture"));

// Fetching user connections
List<User> friendsList = myFriends.getData(); 

for (User userz : friendsList) {
    // System.out.println(userz.getPicture() + " : " + userz.getName());
    response.getWriter().println(userz.getId() + " : " + userz.getName()+" : " + userz.getPicture());
```

NetBeans is not able to find the `getPicture()` method.

Answer (score 1):

no need of any method just use this

```
URL url= new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/<your friends id here>/picture?type=normal");
url.openStream
```